# Cookie not setting in the browser but workers in postman (Express js)

Tags: express, redux, jwt, express-jwt, httponly

am sending the cookie from the backend API (http only cookie ). when I sent the request using postman the cookie setts in the header (Set-Cookie) but when I try sending the request from frontend using redux the cookie don't appear in the browser cookies   

[browser image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu4lq.png)

[Postman image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zdF6.png)

respond header have the cookie
[image of the respond header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iinWQ.png)

**userController.js**

```
// Public
// /users/login GET
// auth user
const authUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  if (!email || !password) {
    res.status(403);
    throw new Error("email or password empty");
  }
  const user = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (!user) {
    res.status(404);
    throw new Error("user not found");
  }

  if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {

    //generate jwt token and send it  
    genToken(res, user._id);


    res.status(200).json({
      message: "User logged in",
      user: {
        id: user._id,
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email,
      },
    });
  } else {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error("email or password not correct");
  }
});
```

**genToken.js**

```
const genToken = (res, userId) => {
  const token = jwt.sign({ userId }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: "30d",
  });

  // set jwt hhtp cookie on the server
  res.cookie("jwt", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false, //////////////// development only
    sameSite: "strict",
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 30 days,
  });
};
```

**redux endpoint for /auth
**

```
    login: builder.mutation({
      query: (data) => ({
        url: `${USERS_URL}/auth`,  // USER_URL=/users
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
      }),
    }),
```

i disabled CORE for the browser using an extencion [moesif](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc?hl=fr)

and installed "cors" package

server.js

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";


const app = express();

var corsOptions = {
  origin: "*",
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204,
  credentials: true,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

but didn't work

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i managed to get it work .

first set the  origin to  "http://localhost:5173"
and  set credentials to "include" in the redux query
and set sameSite to "lax" in the token options
and disable the extinction